# regex match string in range

Tags: php, regex, string

I am new in regular expression and I want to know if following is possible to done with it.

I want to match string with provided positions.

For example

```
$input = 'text example'.
```

I want to match the letters from 4th to 7th, that is

`"t ex"`.

In this case, how can I write the regex?

I tried below

```
'/^.{4,7}.*$/e'
```

its with e filter because I want to use function of it, but this way is not the result I want...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you may use substring for this. Why you need regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use substring for this. If you really want to use regex then try this,

```
preg_match('~^.{3}\K.{4}~', $str);
```

`\K` discards previously matched characters from printing at the final. You may also use positive look-behind instead of `\K`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sH4aN5/1)

Comment: Thank you very much!, I think this is what I want, I will accept this when time limit passed.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? if I want to have 4th and 7th only not in range, how should I change the pattern?